# Value of type Float has no member enumerated

Tags: arrays, swift, enumerate

I have an array. The goal is to, remove the first two index values THEN recall the max 3 values (and later average them). My problem is recalling the 2nd and 3rd max value
My method is to recall max, then remove the max value and call the new array array1, then recall the max value from this array which should be the overall second highest/maximum value.

//To Call Max value

```
var ammendedInitialArray = initialArray.dropFirst(2)        
    var max = Float(-1.0)
    var stepmax1 = Int(-1)
    for (index, value) in ammendedInitialArray.enumerated() {
        if value > max{
            max = value
            stepmax1 = index
        }
```

ABOVE WORKS

```
 ammendedInitialArray1 = ammendedInitialArray.remove(at: stepmax1)
    var max2 = Float(-1.0)
    var stepmax2 = Int(-1)
   *****for (index, value) in ammendedInitialArray1.enumerated{  *****
        if value > max{
            max2 = value
            stepmax2 = index
        }
```

The ***** line comes up with the error: Value of type Float has no member enumerated

Well I didn't mean for it to be a float, I want it to be an array.

Comment: There's a few things here that concern me: **1)** Don't pass a float literal into a float, just assign it directly: `var max2: Float = -1.0`. **2) Do not use [`sentinel values` ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value), like `-1`, `""`, etc. in Swift. This is exactly what optionals are for. I suggest you read through the [language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could do the whole operation this way:

e.g:

```
var initialArray = [2,5,17,1,3,5,14,6,4,8,7,9]

var newArray = initialArray.dropFirst(2).sorted().reversed()
// ^ 17,14,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,1 
let topThreeValues = Array(newArray.prefix(3))
// ^ 17,14,9
topThreeValues.reduce(0, +)/topThreeValues.count
// ^ 13
```

Comment: I like this, would the index of the original still be there.

For example ^17,14,9

I would hope they are adjacent to each other on their index. But if they arent, I would like to know, through printing the index of these values

Comment: @LucasLister ...What?

Comment: The `initialArray` remains untouched. Hence you can still figure out the top three indices. e.g: `topThreeValues.forEach{ print(initialArray.index(of: $0)) }`

Comment: Why are you calling `reversed()`? You could just remove that method call and then later do: `let topThreeValues = Array(newArray.suffix(3))`

Answer (score 0):

[`remove(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1641390-remove) will remove the element from the array in place, and returns the element that has been removed. Not the array.

Try:

```
ammendedInitialArray.remove(at: stepmax1)
var max2 = Float(-1.0)
var stepmax2 = Int(-1)
for (index, value) in ammendedInitialArray.enumerated() {
    if value > max {
        max2 = value
        stepmax2 = index
    }
```

Comment: oh. Well how do I actually remove the max value of this array?

Comment: in the for (index, value) of your comment it gives error

            Type'() -> EnumeratedSequence<ArraySlice<Float>>'does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Comment: I was missing the `()`  after `enumerated`. I copied that bug by accident from the code in your question

Comment: You are a champion. Thanks for not only your fix but also your advice.

Comment: Seriously though. Use optionals.